# Not able to start activity from thread

Tags: java, android

I'm not able to start activity from thread.
I want to start one activity after 2 seconds. But it gives error - application stopped unexpectedly.

Here is the code for the activity from which I want to run the thread.

```
package com.pack.prog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.happy_moments);
            mPlayer.start();

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        sleep(2000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(Splash.this, e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } finally {
                        Intent i = new Intent("com.pack.prog.StartingMenu");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                };
            };
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        try {
            super.onPause();
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            super.onBackPressed();
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception w) {
            Toast.makeText(this, w.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pack.prog"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".StartingMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.pack.prog.STARTINGMENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think there is some problem with the manifest only.

Comment: blahhh... silly me
com.pack.prog.StartingMenu
should be
com.pack.prog.STARTINGMENU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think action name are differnt `"com.pack.prog.StartingMenu"` and in manifest  `"com.pack.prog.STARTINGMENU"`

and also do that in UI thread .....

```
  mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.happy_moments);
  mPlayer.start();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    Intent i = new Intent("com.pack.prog.STARTINGMENU"); //<--- what ever which is right
                    startActivity(i); 
                }
            }, 2000);
```

Comment: I was going to post same thing. But I guess startActivity should get called from UI thread also.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.happy_moments);
    mediaplayer.start();                                                       
        MyThread myThread=new MyThread();
        myThread.start();

}                
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public void run(){
        try{                                      
            Thread.sleep(2000);                
        }                              
        catch(Exception ex){

            Log.e("Welcome Exception :",ex.toString());
        }                      
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);     
    }                   
}
Handler mHandler=new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);                

        if ( )
        {    
            MyThread myThread=new MyThread();
            myThread.start();
        }
        else
        {
     Intent i=new Intent(firstactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**First** Your actions are not matching  `Intent i = new Intent("com.pack.prog.StartingMenu");`
and in manifest it is `<action android:name="com.pack.prog.STARTINGMENU" />`

**Second**
Serious Issue

You can touch UI part in thread you can interact with UI inside thread by enclosing them under `runOnUiThread`.

So change your code to this.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(Splash.this, e.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });

                } finally {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent i = new Intent("com.pack.prog.StartingMenu");
                            startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });

                }

            };
        };
        thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

should use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
                    try {
                        sleep(2000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(Splash.this, e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } finally {
                        Intent i = new Intent("com.pack.prog.StartingMenu");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant perform Ui related stuff from worker thread

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing all time based task using `Timer`. Check the following implementation:

```
Timer t =new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent("com.pack.prog.StartingMenu");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}, 2000);
```